# Passing database connection between intents

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I`m what should I do with my database connection if I change Intent ?

For example I have MainActivity with list of records and button. When I click button I`m starting new Intent (AddActivity). Now in MainActivity I`ve opened database connection to display records. I want to add new record in AddActivity so I need the connection. What should I do ? To be honest I see 2 solutions

1) close connection while invoking new Intent and in AddActivity open it again

2) pass theconnection to AddActivity. But I don`t know how

Or maybe should I do in other way ?

Answer (score 2):

Close the connection. It is a better practice to close the connection and then open it then try to keep it open between activities.

Comment: To be honest, I'm giving a +1 for this despite my own answer, because using a simple DB helper class there's really much need to hold onto anything between Activities. I think that the OP should look at the Android Notepad tutorial, because this uses a DB and has several Activies that access that DB (if I remember right).

Answer (score 1):

Three possible ways come to mind:

1. Use a Service
2. Hold the reference to your DB in an extended Application
3. Hold the reference to your DB in a Singleton

Comment: +1...I think best practice would be to hold reference in an extended Application, because sometime user won't like services running in background and eats battery too. And I am not that great fan of Singleton.

Comment: do you have a good link that i can read about extend Application ?

Comment: Whtat is "extended Application" ?

Comment: Btw if I`ll use Singleton shouldn`t I pass it someway ?